# json result to strongly typed List

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

In a strongly typed view I have a dropdownlist filled with "instruments" from a List from my viewmodel. Everytime the user clicks on an item a musiciansinstrument should appear underneath the dropdownlist.

this is my viewmodel

```
public class RegisterMusicianModel
{
    public RegisterMusicianModel()
    {
        instrumentRepository = new InstrumentRepository();
        instrumentlist = instrumentRepository.FindAllInstruments().ToList<instrument>();
        musicianinstrumentlist = new List<musiciansinstrument>();
    }
    private InstrumentRepository instrumentRepository;
    private List<instrument> instrumentlist;
    private List<musiciansinstrument> musicianinstrumentlist;

    public List<musiciansinstrument> Musicianinstrumentlist
    {
        get { return musicianinstrumentlist; }
        set { musicianinstrumentlist = value; }
    }

    public List<instrument> Instrumentlist
    {
        get { return instrumentlist; }
        set { instrumentlist = value; }
    }


    private musician music = new musician();

    public musician Music
    {
        get { return music; }
        set { music = value; }
    }


}
```

As you can see I have a filled list of instruments, an empty list of musician instruments and an object of musician.
So everytime the user changes selection in the dropdownlist this method gets called and returns a JSON Object (musiciansinstrument, not an instrument).

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult AjaxInstrumentsMusician(int id)
    {
        musiciansinstrument mi = new musiciansinstrument();
        mi.idInstruments = id;
        mi.Instrumentname = instrumentrepo.GetInstrument(id).name;

        return Json(mi);
    }
```

the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Instrumentlist').change(function (e) {
        var myval = $('#Instrumentlist').val();
        alert(myval);
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Account/AjaxInstrumentsMusician",
            type: "POST",
            data: { id: myval },
            success: function (result) {
                alert(result.Instrumentname);
            },
            error: function () {
                alert('failed');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

I can display the JSON object properties in my view wherever I want, that's ok. But what I really want is to add it to the strongly typed object (The empty List from the viewmodel). So i can acces it from my viewmodel parameter in my HTTPPOST method. I'm not a big fan of FormCollection, extra parameters, ViewBags, ...

I'm kinda new to the concept JSON and I couldn't find any good explanation on this on google. Is this possible? Is there another elegant way of solving this issue?

Comment: Hardly can understand what you want to do. Populate list when user selects instrument? populate it before presenting to view ? or use model in json method ?

Comment: I have a JSONresult I can use in my view. I want to add it to a List defined in my viewmodel, since it's a strongly typed View I was hoping I could acces the JSON result in the model.musicianinstrumentlist property when the user submits the form `[HttpPost] public ActionResult RegisterMusician(RegisterMusicianModel model) { model.musicianinstrumentlist; return null; }` Is this possible to achieve?